# Speed of JSON deserilization in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, listview, windows-phone-8.1, deserialization

I'm developing app for Windows Phone 8.1 and I'm using  REST API and JSON to communicating with the database . It is all working, but I have a problem with speed deserialize JSON and loading data into the ListView. When I'm loading small data (about 20-30 items) apllication is fluently, but if there are more than 100 items I'm waiting even 4-5 seconds to load to ListView. Does anyone know efficient way to solve it? :) It is problem of deserialization or problem of loading to ListView ?

Here is SC of deserialize

```
   List<dataInfo> VypisZakazekli = new List<dataInfo>();
 private async void DeserializeData(string json)
    {
        //MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog(json);
        //await msg.ShowAsync();
        this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = null;

        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<dataInfo>));
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        var obj = (List<dataInfo>)ser.ReadObject(stream);



        VypisZakazekli.Clear();

        foreach (dataInfo di in obj)
        {
            string barva = "";
            string iZakazka = di.zakazka;
            string sNazev = di.nazev;
            string sKod = di.kod_firmy;
            string sStatus = "Status: " + di.status_v;
            string sDruh = di.druh_zakazky;
            switch(di.barva)
            {
                case "ZE": barva = "#FF32FF1D"; break;
                case "CE": barva = "#FFFF1D1D"; break;
                case "ZL": barva = "#FFF5FF1D"; break;
                case "OR": barva = "#FFFFA31D"; break;
                case "MO": barva = "#FF1D46FF"; break;
                default: barva="x:Null"; break;

            }

            VypisZakazekli.Add(new dataInfo(iZakazka, sNazev, sKod, sStatus, sDruh,barva));
        }


        this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = VypisZakazekli;


    }
```

and here is DataInfo Class

```
[DataContract]
class dataInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string zakazka { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string nazev { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string kod_firmy { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string status_v { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string druh_zakazky { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string barva { get; set; }



    public dataInfo(string Zakazka, string Nazev, string Kod, string Status, string Druh, string Barva)
    {
        this.zakazka = Zakazka;
        this.nazev = Nazev;
        this.kod_firmy = Kod;
        this.status_v = Status;
        this.druh_zakazky = Druh;
        this.barva = Barva;

    }
}
```

and here is XAML ListVIew

```
 <ListView SelectionMode="None" x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="0,0,-0.167,0.167"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                                <Grid Background="#FF464242" Margin="0,0,0,10" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                                    <!--<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                        <MenuFlyout>
                                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Detail zakázky" Click="Detail" />
                                        </MenuFlyout>
                                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>-->
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Rectangle  Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{Binding barva}" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,10,10" >

                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding nazev}" Foreground="White"  FontSize="21"  />

                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding zakazka}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="#FFFFEC31" />
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding kod_firmy}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="20,0,0,0"   />

                                        </StackPanel>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few speed ups

- Use Json.Net to deserialise (Not sure if works on Windows 8.1)
- Instead of requesting all data, ask for 20 items at a time asynchronously.  This will be appear to end user as much faster.

Comment: None of those are the problem, although I agree Json.Net should be used. If you add 20 items at a time, still the UI thread will struggle to create the UI items making the application marginally more responsive, but still unusable. UI virtualization is the only way to trully free the UI thread and make the application responsive.

Comment: @SKleanthous, I said asynchronously, so the app is not waiting on the UI threading.  This is sometimes called `infinite scrolling` and has been used for many years.

Comment: If you add the items asynchronously, the data will be added to the collection asynchronously and in a background thread, but the UI thread will still have to instantiate the UI items in the view that will show the new data in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

First, why is the method `DeserializeData` marked as `async`? You do not `await` anything in it. If you thought that marking a method with `async` makes it asynchronous, that is not how `async` works.

The JSON deserialization is not the problem. Your are giving the `ListView` all the items at once, which is not ideal. Create an `ObservableCollection` and bind it to the `ListView`. Then you can add your items to this collection one by one not making the `ListView` halt.

Comment: Could you post example ? I tryed to create ObservableCollection, but it is the same as List. How i can add Items one by one ?

Comment: using binding is the important thing, bind the collection to the `ItemsSource` property of your `ListView`. Your problem is `this.ListBox1.ItemsSource = VypisZakazekli;` (horrible czech naming btw.) which sends all the data to the `ListView` at once. Take a look at MVVM, this code-behind is a disaster